# Drawing animation on torus with python?

Tags: python, animation, plot

I recently worked on a code that allowed to display a simulation of particles' motions in a periodical space. In concrete terms, it resulted in a 2D plot provided with N points (N ~ 10^4) initially gathered at the center, then spread out according to a matching velocity. As it is a periodical space, any points that would go beyond the upper limit is actually brought back to the lower limit, and vice versa. To illustrate, here are two images :

**Initial positions**

[image]

**After a certain time**

[image]

Each points are supposed to travel horizontally, either to the right or to the left (respectively positive or negative velocity).

I programmed it using Python, but now, in the scope of my project, I'd like to simulate the same thing but on a torus. To give you a good glimpse of how it looked like, please take a look at the following pic :

**Transformation from a rectangle to a torus**

[image]

(Imagine my initial 2D plan is the initial rectangle, which I'd like to transform into the final torus).

Therefore, in that case we would see every particle moving on the surface of the torus. The previous 1st picture would correspond to particles gathered on a "single" circus of the torus, and the previous 2nd picture would correspond to the "filling up" the entire surface of the torus.

Since my code for previous simulations was written in Python, I am wondering if I can still use it for this task. If so, I'd like to have some clues about how to do it, and otherwise, what would be the best language to use for this ?

I hope I have been clear. I apologize in advance for some mistakes I could have done with English.

Comment: How will you represent your torus in 2D space?
Do you imagine a 3D plot, or will you calculate each particles path along its "torus space" and then somehow project this movement to a square 2D window?

Comment: @VegardKT Thanks for your answer. I would think 3D plot is better, the picture was only here to show the transformation so you can visualize how the particles would behave on the torus.

Comment: What you need is to map the 2D position of the point on the torus surface onto a 3D space using t[orus equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus), then create a 3D plot using python

Comment: So I guess your question is really; "How do i calculate a particles path on a torus"?

Comment: @bracco23 So I would first map all positions on a 2D plot, then plot them with matching positions on the 3D torus using its equation ?

Comment: @Tiranyk yeah, I mean that is the basic idea. You already have a 2D plot, just need to map that surface in a 3D space

Comment: @bracco23 All right. Thanks for your help both of you ! I should handle it.